# Why does my ValidateForm seem to be skipping some functions?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Im trying to build a form using HTML and Javascript. I ran into an issue and I cannot wrap my head around it. Maybe it is something meaningless that I am not noticing.

I am calling a ValidateForm function which in turn calls other functions to validate each field of the form. They then return a value to either submit or not submit the form.

The function validateName() checks if the name field is filled and the function checkMinLength() checks if the field nr_bi as at least 7 digits in it.

If I run the code as it is and leave the name field empty but fill correctly the nr_bi field, it tells me to fill the name field. It works correctly.

If I do the inverse by correctly filling the name field but leaving the nr_BI field empty, I receive no warning that it must have at least 7 digits.

I am trying to find the error but cant seem to.

Thank you.

```js
function validateForm() {
  if(!validateName() || !checkMinLength()) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validateName() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["nome"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Por favor preencha todos os campos");
    return false;
  }
}

function checkMinLength(){
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["nr_bi"].value;
  if (x.length < 7) {
    alert("O BI tem de ter pelo menos 7 digitos");
    return false; 
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Formulário</h1>
       
  <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    </p>Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" size="35">
    </p>Número do B.I.: <input type="text" name="nr_bi" size="35">
    </p>Ano do Nascimento: <input type="text" name="ano" size="35">
    </p>Mês do Nascimento: <input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" name="mes" size="10">
    </p>Correio Electrónico: <input type="text" name="email" size="35">

    <br><br>     

    <INPUT TYPE="RESET" VALUE="Limpar">
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is very simple!

```
(!validateName() || !checkMinLength())
```

this means that if either  is valid or TRUE, it is accepted.

replace that with

```
(!validateName() && !checkMinLength())
```

use && instead of ||

Comment: Silly me. Is it because it was not even bothering checking the 2nd function since the 1st one was already returning a value? I was trying to follow an answer from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412913/javascript-code-returns-false-but-still-the-form-is-submittted since their Answer was not working for me.